# How do I replace an existing Community file on IBM SmartCloud

Tags: ibm-sbt

I am trying to replace an existing Community file using the following java

```
Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramsMap.put("createVersion", "false");
fileEntry = fileService.updateCommunityFile(fis, fileUuid, fileName, communityLibraryId, paramsMap);
```

But it is returning a HTTP 411:Length required error.

I am using the latest build (1.1.5.20150520-1200.jar)

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what i am missing?

Comment: add content-length to your headers sent via fileservice

Comment: add content-length to your headers sent via fileservice.  411 means there is no content-length.  I'll have someone on our dev team look at it.

Comment: @Paul, the error shows that Content-Length is already in the header. It now includes the content-length I have added.  The error = Request to url https://apps.na.collabserv.com/files/basic/api/library/... /document/... /entry?content-length=6600&createVersion=false returned an error response 411:Length Required HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required [Server: AkamaiGHost, Mime-Version: 1.0, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: 221, Expires: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 09:10:14 GMT, Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 09:10:14 GMT, Connection: close]

Comment: still sounds like the content-length is missing. a member of the team will lok at it

Answer (score 1):

I tried recreating the issue but I am able to upload New version of Community file correctly with and without version, using the updateCommunityFile API. I do not get any Length related error. This is the snippet I am using :

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C://TestUploadCommunity.txt");
FileInputStream fis = null;
try { 
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //TODO
}
fileEntry = fileService.updateCommunityFile(fis, fileEntry.getFileId(), fileEntry.getLabel(), communityLibraryId, params);
```

Can you share more details on your sample, what exactly is your fis? 
I have tried this on 2 environments and I do not see any issue.

Also, from the entry you have pasted,

```
"Request to url apps.na.collabserv.com/files/basic/api/library... /document/... /entry?content-length=6600&createVersion=false returned an error response 411:Length Required HTTP/1.1 411"
```

It seems that somehow an incorrect content-length is passed for your request. 
Can you share the sample that you are using?

Comment: Hi @Vimal, Sorry for the delay getting back to you, I have been on holiday.

Comment: Hi @Vimal, fis = new FileInputStream(filePath); where String filePath = args[1]; it containing the full path of the file to replace the existing community file.

Comment: Hi @Vimal, I have tried defining the filePath as a java.io.File as shown in your example. I still get the HTTP 411 error. How is the comtent length defined in the example?

Comment: the 411 error should be removed, and you should be able to upload.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I am not sure what you mean by your reply?